# A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to unity and game development and also coding, just started today, and I'm literally just trying to get my player to WALK but i've encountered my first issue, i keep getting this error message but there are no signs of anything wrong with my code (In my eyes, it might be very obvious to you) but i really need help

I've tried redoing it many different ways. I am following a tutorial for character movement, but it's from 2018 on a different version of visual studio code.

```
 public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {};

     public CharacterController2D controller;
```

here's the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwcT-Dch0bA&t=341s i'm very new so if you could send a link to a helpful 2d game design tutorial that would be FANTASTIC.

Comment: The error means you need to put `public CharacterController2D controller;` inside a class. Was it supposed to go inside the braces for your PlayerMovement class? Or were they both supposed to go inside another class? Can you link to the tutorial please?

Comment: As the error said: A `namespace` cannot directly contain the field `controller`. As Rup said it has to be in a class, probably `PlayerMovement`.

Comment: Thanks. Skimming the video, here's the point where we see the code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwcT-Dch0bA&t=521s You can see that the controller line is inside the braces of the class definition, as in jPhizzle's answer.

Comment: thank you so much!! i'm sorry to waste your time with a simple mistake but i appreciate you helping me out with it!

Comment: Here's the completed file: https://github.com/Brackeys/2D-Movement/blob/master/2D%20Movement/Assets/PlayerMovement.cs You can download the project from GitHub too.

Comment: this is such a helpful community wow

Answer (score 6):

This should get rid of your error

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController2D controller;
}
```

The error message is pretty straight forward. You can't *directly* have methods or declare variables inside a namespace

You *can*, however, have **classes** *inside* namespaces and those classes *can* *directly* contain members such as fields or methods. For instance you have a class called `PlayerMovement` and is inheriting `MonoBehaviour`.

*"What's a namespace?"*, you ask?

The namespace is the location of your classes *and* is the first opening bracket in the cs file.

Here's an example that's easy to grasp

```
namespace This.Is.My.Address
{
    public class House
    {
        private Room LivingRoom {get; set;}

        private Water Faucet()
        {
             //return Water or something
        }
    }
}
```

So within the This.Is.My.Address namespace, resides a house, and within that house are a bunch of house stuff.

What you did was this (I hope you can spot the difference):

```
namespace This.Is.My.Address
{
    public class House 
    {

    }

    private Room LivingRoom {get; set;}

    private Water Faucet()
    {
        //return Water() or something
    }
}
```

You had your living room and etc. out on the street and everything. Hope that helps explain it for you.

Answer (score 2):

`C#` is an Object Oriented Programming (OOP) type language, and as the name suggests, it deals with what we call 'objects'. Objects are created by using a 'template', which we call a `class` in OOP.

So, the way a class is defined is as follows:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // Stuff goes inside here
}
```

And these classes go inside what we call `namespace`, which is sort of like a virtual bucket where classes are put in. And these namespaces are allowed to contain classes, but not fields as the error suggests.

So, this is not okay because the field is directly inside the namespace:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
     public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {};

     public CharacterController2D controller;
}
```

But this will be, since the field is inside the class:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        public CharacterController2D controller;
    }
}
```

It looks like you're super new to programming, so I suggest to you to not start with Unity, which is a bit advanced. You should probably start with simple programming tutorials and try to understand the basic programming concepts before moving into big projects.